# How To Solve a Index Error Problem With a For Loop

Tags: python, index-error

I'm facing a problem where I can't finish my code.
There is a problem where upon running this code it comes up as an IndexError.

```
name = str(input("Please input the books name that you would like to borrow: ")
file = open("books.txt", "r")

file_contents = []
for line in file:
    stripped_line = line.strip()
    line_list = stripped_line.split()
    file_contents.append(line_list)
file.close()
i = 0
for name in range(len(file_contents)):
    i = i +1
    if name == file_contents[i]:
        table_3= [["Borrow Book","1"],
                    ["Cancel Borrowing","2"]]
        headers_3 = ["Details", "No."]
        print(tabulate(table_3, headers_3, tablefmt = "grid"))
        num = int(input("Please input 1 for confirmation of booking and 2 for canceling the booking: "))
        file_contents[i] = changed_name
        changed_name = str(changed_name)
```

```
if name == file_contents[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
Example Of The File: 
(books.txt)
Exile
Dancing In The Moonlight
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: There is a new problem that came up.

Comment: That sounds like the start of a new question. In the mean time we can help you with this question.

Comment: In Python the correct way to iterate over a sequence is to iterate over the objects in the sequence - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements - and if you need to also know the index of the current item use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Just noticed, you're overwriting your input on line 1 with your naming the for loop variable as "name". Try "title" or something for one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your complete solution . I hope it would help You

```
from tabulate import tabulate

name = str(input("Please input the books name that you would like to borrow: "))
file = open("books.txt", "r")

file_contents = []   #available books
for line in file:
    line=line.strip()
    file_contents.append(line)
file.close()   
print("file content: ",file_contents)
i = 0
if name in file_contents:
    table_3= [["Borrow Book","1"],["Cancel Borrowing","2"]]
    headers_3 = ["Details", "No."]
    print(tabulate(table_3, headers_3, tablefmt = "grid"))
    num = int(input("Please input 1 for confirmation of booking and 2 for canceling the booking: "))
    if(num==1):
        try:
            #user wants to withdraw that books so we've to remove that book from our available list of books 
            file_contents.remove(name)
            #now we remove that book name from our available books.txt file
            file=open("books.txt","w")
            str1=" "
            str1.join(file_contents)
            file.write(str1)
            print("Happy to serve you :-)  visit again for more good books")  
        except Exception as e:
            print("There is an error ",e)

    else:
        print("visit again for more good books")
```

Comment: Accept my answer and upvote it if it is helpful. There is tick below the downvote ...click on it

Answer (score 2):

You're missing with `range` keyword

Try this

```
for name in range(len(file_contents)):
           #your work
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Please help me with the second problem

Comment: Ok let me open my device

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do.

Comment: for name in range(len(file_contents)):
    i = i +1
    print("---",name)
    print("____",file_contents[i])                               Please input the books name that you would like to borrow: Exile
--- 0
____ ['Dancing', 'in', 'the', 'moonlight']
--- 1

Comment: Can please type in python code. I'm a beginner so I  don't understand the code you gave me

Comment: Can you tell le me exact problem statement

Comment: Ohk i got it...but can you tell me what is changed name?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to iterate through the `file_contents`:

```
# code above elided
file.close()
for line in file_contents:
    if name == line:
# following code elided
```

Comment: if name == file_contents[i]:
IndexError: list index out of range: This is the second problem that came up after changing the code

Comment: Well, don't do that.  Use the iteration as I outlined.

Comment: Sorry, but the iteration that you gave me is not working.

Comment: It's not continuing the line after the iteration

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, an int cannot be iterable. How can you loop through 4?

The solution? Create a range of numbers:

```py
for name in range(len(file_names)):
```

Answer (score -1):

It would help if you posted the IndexError that you are getting.
And an example of the file you are opening?

What i think i could discover, is that you are using variable i als iterator, but i cannot find it in your loop.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Please send me the modified code after discovering my problem towards the code.